# Round up number to highest nearest 9 in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I want to round up a number to highest nearest 9, Here is an example

(12,24,37,75,80)

if i gave this inputs want to get output like below given

(19,29,39,79,89)

I am using PHP(laravel), Please Help Me.

Comment: Can you elaborate _highest nearest 9_ even more?

Comment: suppose 12 is an input number i want to get 19, or if 24 is input output should be 29.

Comment: So basically you just want to replace the last digit with 9.

Comment: @MUHAMMEDJABIRC Still unclear. What is the answer for 90?

Comment: for 90 also i need 99

Comment: @nice_dev Below answer is worked for me, Thnak you for the reply

Comment: @MUHAMMEDJABIRC Questions on SO should be clear anyway so that future readers who refer to your question can understand what was asked and what was answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$input = [12,24,37,75,80];

$output = array_map(function($num) {
    return (int)($num / 10) * 10 + 9;
}, $input);
```

Comment: @MUHAMMEDJABIRC For 90, is it 91 or 99 or maybe 90 itself?

Answer (score 1):

I like the simplicity of @HTMHell's answer. And it works perfectly for integers. However, I found, that when using real numbers as input, something like `19.999` will be "rounded up" to `19`.

I therefore suggest the following, modified version:

```
echo json_encode(array_map(function($v){
  return ceil(($v+1)/10)*10-1;
},[12,18.99,19.01,24,37,75,80,90]));
// [19,19,29,29,39,79,89,99]
```

And, to answer @nice_dev's question, `90` should be rounded up to `99`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$items = array(12,24,37,75,80);
$endDigit = 9; //this should be between 0-9
$newItems = array();
foreach($items as $item){
  $final = (int)($item / 10) * 10 + $endDigit;
  array_push($newItems,$final); 
}
print_r($newItems);
```

---

Output

```
Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => 29 [2] => 39 [3] => 79 [4] => 89 )
```

Comment: Have you tested your function with `$endDigit=3`? The result is `[13,23,33,73,83]`. That is not the intended "rounding up" behaviour.